# RubyGem version downgrade

Tags: ruby

When the command of `sudo rake db:migrate` was executed the error message below appeared.

```
rake aborted!
RubyGem version error: rack(1.4.1 not ~> 1.1.0)
```

I guess the RubyGem version is later than the expected one.
How can I downgrade the version of RubyGem?

Comment: Can you try again without the `sudo` part? It still should work.

Answer (score 1):

A "too new" version of RubyGems can indeed be a problem with some older applications (mostly those who still use Rails 2.x), but the error message you posted seems to indicate a different cause. Your applications wants a specific version of the Rack gem and the version(s) you have installed probably don't fit that request.

Your applications calls for rack ~> 1.1.0. That condition is matched by any version in the 1.1.x series, for example 1.1.0, 1.1.5 or 1.1.345, but not 1.2.0 or 2.0.0. You seem to have installed Rack in 1.4.1, that does not match the condition ~> 1.1.0.

Fortunately you can install different versions of the same gem side by side. To check which version(s) of Rack you have installed you can use

```
gem list -l rack
```

That lists are locally installed (because of the -l switch) gems whose name starts with 'rack'. In that list there's probably no version of the 1.1.x series.

To install a specific version of a gem you can use the --version=x.y.z option, in your case

```
gem install rack --version=1.1.0
```

Chances are that your migrations run through with that.

If you actually need to downgrade RubyGems, you first need to install the RubyGems gem ( :D ) in the version you want to downgrade to analogous to what you did above, e. g.

```
gem install rubygems-update --version=x.y.z
```

Then you can do execute the "update" (in your case, the downgrade)

```
gem update --system x.y.z
```

where x.y.z is the version number you want. Be aware that "updating" to a specific version has been introduced in RubyGems 1.5.1, so you can't downgrade to any version below that.